# Assigned variable mysteriously becomes null

Tags: java, android

I have class:

```
public class Nomenklatura implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>(6);
}
```

And Activity:

```
public class Smena extends Activity {
    public Nomenklatura Asortiment;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>(6);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.smena); 
        Intent i= getIntent();

        Asortiment = (Nomenklatura) i.getExtras().getSerializable("Nomenklatura");
        ArrayList<String> data = Asortiment.data;
        ArrayList<String> data1 = Asortiment.data1;
        ArrayList<String> data2= Asortiment.data2;
    }
}
```

In debugger, before `ArrayList<String> data =Asortiment.data;`I see data in Asortiment.data, but after this operation, `ArrayList<String> data` is empty. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onCreate method is making new local variables, instead of assigning to the member variables.  If you write `data = Asortiment.data;` without the preceding `ArrayList<String>` declaration (and the same on the following two lines), it will work!